# Visual Studio 2019 Community 16.8.4 crashes when drag and drop Tab

Tags: visual-studio-2019

Visual Studio 2019 Community 16.8.4 crashes when drag and drop Document Tab.

I have re-installed VS 2019 Community and it does not fix the problem.  I have been using 2019 Community for a year now with no problem. Not sure if it is related to 16.8.4 or not.

Has anyone else had this problem? If so have you figured out how to fix it?

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/854228/vs-1641-crashs-when-undocking-tabs-with-tab-layout.html

Comment: submit a new issue and upload the crash dumps

Comment: Submit where? Include link.

Comment: The [link explains it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/feedback-options?view=vs-2019#report-a-problem)

Comment: How is it possible it worked before and stopped working with update?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Indeed fixed in 16.8.5 as specified here: https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/Unexpected-VS-crash-when-docking-or-spli/1323017

Comment: According to the link the source of the problem was with a Windows update, KB4598299 or KB4598301 and was fixed with VS 16.8.5.  I'm having the same problem with SSMS 15.0.18369.0 and have submitted a bug report.

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio v18.6 is also affected.

Answer (score 15):

[Workaround]

Edit %InstallRoot%\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.config and %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_xxx\devenv.exe.config and append the following text to the AppContextSwitchOverrides element’s value attribute:

```
;Switch.System.Windows.Interop.MouseInput.OptOutOfMoveToChromedWindowFix=true;Switch.System.Windows.Interop.MouseInput.DoNotOptOutOfMoveToChromedWindowFix=true
```

After restarting VS, you should be able to drag your VS windows around without crashing.
https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/Unexpected-VS-crash-when-docking-or-spli/1323017#T-N1330689

Answer (score 0):

It's just started doing it today, been fine on this version up to this point. It only seems to be the docking so I have Visual Studio on the left hand side of the screen then I'm floating editor windows on the right. Seems to be OK like that.

Answer (score 0):

I have VS2015 and the updates that are supposedly causing the crash weren't installed. Instead I got KB5001028 and KB4601056 installed on the 15th and docking any windows in Visual Studio crashed immediately. Removing those updates fixed the crashing partially. Now I'll get random crashes when docking and immediately switching windows, but not always.

Answer (score 0):

Updating visual studio 2017 to its latest minor version, fixed issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

For those who can't find a solution shall try this.
For me, none of the solutions worked. I've updated to latest version and even tried all windows updates recommended.

Finally I figured it out that it was due to eXtra Buttons application. Once the eXtra Buttons is closed, everything was back to normal. Please share if this fix works.